# Problem with TikZ path label orientation

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I'm a newbie to LaTeX. I wanted to group and name the rectangles like the image below so I tried this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,decorations.text}
  \tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em, minimum width = 6cm, text width = 5cm}}
  \tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}
\begin{document}
\resizebox {\columnwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node [box]                     (1) {Node};
        \node [box, below=0.5cm of 1]   (2) {Node};
        \node [box, below=0.5cm of 2]   (3) {Node};
        \node [box, below=0.5cm of 3]   (4) {Node};

        \path [line] (1)  --  (2);
        \path [line] (2)  --  (3);
        \path [line] (3)  --  (4);
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={raise=-2ex, text along path, text align=center,text={PATH LABEL}}}] (4.west) -- ++(-15pt, 0) |- (1.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Above code produces this
[image]
But I want to rotate the text inside the decoration (path label) and make it look like this.

[image]

Also, if the raise is something positive, the label will come on the left but I won't be able to see it in the pdf. I can see it when `raise = 0ex`.

Is there a better way to write the code?

Comment: If you want to see the text if `raise` is positive, you should add option `margin=...` to the document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very unsophisticated though simple and working proposal.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em, minimum width = 6cm, text width = 5cm}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node [box]                     (1) {Node};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of 1]   (2) {Node};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of 2]   (3) {Node};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of 3]   (4) {Node};

    \path [line] (1)  --  (2);
    \path [line] (2)  --  (3);
    \path [line] (3)  --  (4);
    \draw [thick] (4.west) -- ++(-15pt, 0) |- (1.west) node[pos=0.25,left,align=center]{
    P\\[-0.2ex] A\\[-0.2ex] T\\[-0.2ex]H\\[-0.2ex] \\[-0.2ex]L\\[-0.2ex] A\\[-0.2ex] B\\[-0.2ex] E\\[-0.2ex] L
    };  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a more sophisticated version: simply replace `text along path` by `text effects along path`. (I do not know how much sense `\columnwidth` in a `standalone` document makes.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.text}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em, minimum width = 6cm, text width = 5cm}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node [box]                     (1) {Node};
        \node [box, below=0.5cm of 1]   (2) {Node};
        \node [box, below=0.5cm of 2]   (3) {Node};
        \node [box, below=0.5cm of 3]   (4) {Node};

        \path [line] (1)  --  (2);
        \path [line] (2)  --  (3);
        \path [line] (3)  --  (4);
        \draw 
        [thick] (1.west) -- ++(-15pt, 0) coordinate(aux) |- (4.west);
        \path[decorate, decoration={raise=-2ex,
        text effects along path, 
        text align=center,
        text={PATH LABEL}}] (aux) -- (aux|-4.center);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `pre length` to shift the text on the original path like this `\draw[decoration={text effects along path, raise=-2ex, pre length=5mm, text={PATH LABEL}},postaction={decorate}] (1.west) --  ++(-15pt, 0) |- (4.west);`